# Generating hash with Argon2 on Botan results in garbage data and 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000100000000

Tags: c++, cryptography, botan, argon2-ffi

I'm trying to hash passwords using the C++ cryptography library Botan. I've tried testing out the library using the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <botan/argon2.h>
#include <botan/system_rng.h>

int main() {
    Botan::System_RNG rng;
    std::string password = "cool_password";

    std::string generated_hash = Botan::argon2_generate_pwhash(password.c_str(), 
    password.length(), rng, 1, 4000, 1); // crash occurs here

    std::cout << generated_hash << "\n";
}
```

but the code either printed garbage data, or gave me a runtime error:
`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFEF11825E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000100000000.`

What should I do? Using other hashing methods such as Botan::generate_bcrypt() also resulted in the same error.

Comment: Was everything built with the exactly the same tool-chain and version ?

Comment: Yup, built everything with nmake following the tutorial on https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/building.html#on-windows

Comment: If you compile your own program with `-fsanitize=address` you may get more info about where it crashes.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have included that. It crashes when I use the argon2_generate_pwhash() function.

Comment: I just downloaded, compiled and installed botan and then compiled your program (with `-fsanitize=address` and more) - no problem. It prints lines like `$argon2id$v=19$m=4000,t=1,p=1$OAeT30yqV111xsvTjN43Rg$k5uwQIc2mNREuXRCTVZ4VuWdEbR4dumvDfHCkm0Bl2s` every time I run it.

Comment: Must be a problem with my build then. I'll try re-building it, thank you very much for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 hours of painful troubleshooting and rebuilding the library with different compilers over and over, I have found out that Botan does not work properly if "solution configuration" is not set to "Release" rather than "Debug" in Visual Studio.